# Determine hardware-age of an Android device

Tags: 5.0-lollipop, sony-xperia-z

How can I get information that gives indication of the age of hardware in an Android device. I would look for lifetime information like how often has the battery been charged, how long has the screen has been turned on, how long has the flash memory been active.

In a traditional computer I would mainly look for SMART data. I would prefer solutions with basic android system information, and definitely want to avoid rooting the device.

The background is that I have bought a new Sony Xperia Z4 tablet  (5.0.2), but the condition of the packaging leads me to believe that it is not brand new. The package was secured only with a single unevenly cut tape and the plastic pocket is somewhat dirty. the screen protection is not quite centered and has a few bubbles. I don't really care if it has been been slightly in use and is still in new condition, but I am curious and definitely want to avoid a device that has been under more than minor use.

Comment: Not really an answer to your question, but you might be able to get the manufacture date by contacting Sony and providing the serial number, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Find the tag which is attached to your device where serial number and manufacturing details are encoded. This resides beneath the back cover on most devices. Sony provides the manufacturing date as eg: 16W10(W stands for week) which is 22nd March 2016. This might help you find the Hardware age of your device. Thank you.